# Finding the relative pose of a robot gripper

Tags: ros, forward-kinematics, arm-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot arm with a gripper. I know the gripper pose (relative to the robot base coordinate system) at any moment. At startup, I record the pose of the gripper and set this as the original pose `O`. Then, the gripper moves to its new pose `N`, again in the robot base coordinate system. What I want to calculate, is `R`, the relative pose of the gripper *in the coordinate system of the original pose* `O`, rather than in the coordinate system of the robot base, which would just be `N`.

So, `O` = original pose, `N` = new pose, `R` = relative pose

From my calculations:

`O` * `R` = `N`

Therefore:

`R` = `O^-1` * `N`

However, from my observations, `R` is the pose of the hand relative to the original pose, but in the coordinate system of the robot base. I want it to be in the coordinate system of the original pose. How do I get this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203267/finding-the-relative-pose-of-a-robot-gripper/) by [Karnivaurus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21659/karnivaurus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're asking how to implement the solution in ROS, [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) is a powerful library that should exactly suits your need.

If you're asking general robotics ideas, this forum is not the place for it. I recommend to ask on [robotics.stackexchange.com](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0